# Weird relative import resolution error in python 3.2.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, relative-import

I encoutner the following import resolution error in a program of mine:

```
I am: homie.translators.is24.rest.translator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/sbin/is24rest", line 3, in <module>
    from homie.interfaces.is24.rest import __main__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie/interfaces/is24/rest/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .exporter import Exporter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie/interfaces/is24/rest/exporter.py", line 12, in <module>
    from homie.translators.is24.rest.translator import Translator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie/translators/is24/rest/translator.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .factories.rest.restFactory import RestFactory
ImportError: No module named factories.rest.restFactory
```

The content of `/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie/translators/is24/rest/translator.py` is

```
"""
Created on 18.06.2014

@author: Richard Neumann
"""
print('I am: ' + str(__name__))
from homie.translators.abc import Translator as T

from .factories.rest.restFactory import RestFactory
from .factories.openimmo.openimmoFactory import OpenImmoFactory


class Translator(T):
<snip>
```

Also, the relative module exists:

```
root@srv:/usr/src/is24-translator# ls /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/homie/translators/is24/rest/factories/rest/
abc.py  attachments  __init__.py  __pycache__  realestates  restFactory.py
```

Why does python3 try to do an absolute import here?
I do only encounter this problem under Debian 7 with python 3.2.3.
Under Arch w/ python 3.4.1 it works just fine.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was the __init__.py missing in `.factories`, which caused this error.
Took me a while to realize that.